# Spring cloud config client disables database health check

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, health-check

I am running a spring.boot application that fetches config from a spring-cloud config server. The application is quite simple, a rest api that hits an Oracle database. In the application context there is an Oracle datasource wrapped i a Hihari pool.

When running /actuator/health the db health check is not triggered. Output:

```
{
  status: "UP",
  components: {
    clientConfigServer: {
      status: "UP",
      details: {
        propertySources: [
          "configClient",
          "/var/git-repo/xxx/xxx-localhost.yml",
          "/var/git-repo/application-localhost.properties",
          "/var/git-repo/xxx/xxx.yml",
          "/var/git-repo/application.properties"
        ]
      }
    },
    discoveryComposite: {
      description: "Discovery Client not initialized",
      status: "UNKNOWN",
      components: {
        discoveryClient: {
          description: "Discovery Client not initialized",
          status: "UNKNOWN"
        }
      }
    },
    diskSpace: {
      status: "UP",
      details: {
        total: 1587526397952,
        free: 1272794873856,
        threshold: 10485760
      }
    },
    ping: {
      status: "UP"
    },
    refreshScope: {
      status: "UP"
    }
  }
}
```

However, if i turn of the config server and instead use local config through: spring.cloud.config.enabled=false the output is:

```
{
  status: "UP",
  components: {
    db: {
      status: "UP",
      details: {
        database: "Oracle",
        result: "Hello",
        validationQuery: "SELECT 'Hello' from DUAL"
      }
    },
    discoveryComposite: {
      description: "Discovery Client not initialized",
      status: "UNKNOWN",
      components: {
        discoveryClient: {
          description: "Discovery Client not initialized",
          status: "UNKNOWN"
        }
      }
    },
    diskSpace: {
      status: "UP",
      details: {
        total: 1587526397952,
        free: 1272794869760,
        threshold: 10485760
      }
    },
    ping: {
      status: "UP"
    },
    refreshScope: {
      status: "UP"
    }
  }
}
```

I am sure there is an explanation to this but I cannot seem to find it so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: connectivity to config server itself has nothing to do with it. My guess is there is something in the configuration from config server that is disabling it or disabling the datasource? Take a look at `/actuator/env` after app is running.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out spencergibb was absolutely right. In the common application.properties someone added management.health.db.enabled=false about five years ago. Mystery solved.